# VBA: IE automation stops with new tab open

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

A link that I click on via IE automation opens a new tab. With this new tab how can I control it with out creating a new internet explorer object?

```
If Format(IE.Document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvExtract").getElementsByTagName("tr")(1).getElementsByTagName("td")(2).innerText, "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS") = Format(ExtractDate, "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS") Then 'compair date to see if this is the correct file to download.
    IE.Document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvExtract").getElementsByTagName("tr")(1).getElementsByTagName("td")(1).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click ' select file to download
Sleep (100)
Progs "Downloading Extract"
'IE.Visible = False
'<a href='javascript:OpenDownloadWindow("../Common/FileDownloader.aspx?fileKey=2945596")'>Work Order Inquiry - Work Order</a>
End If
IEBusy
Do
wHandle = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Internet Explorer")
IEBusy
If wHandle = 0 Then
Else
    IE.Visible = True
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").AppActivate wHandle
    SendKeys "{TAB}", True
    SendKeys "~", True
    Exit Do
End If
DoEvents
Sleep (100)
Loop
```

This anchor is the hyper link that is being clicked on `<a href='javascript:OpenDownloadWindow("../Common/FileDownloader.aspx?fileKey=2945596")'>Work Order Inquiry - Work Order</a>`

It opens to a new tab that I seem to have no automated control over.

Comment: Can you include the code you have already written and highlight which part you are stuck on?

Comment: @destination-data Thanks for the question. I updated my post with the relevant code.

Comment: You could extract the URL (`../Common/FileDownloader.aspx?fileKey=2945596`) and use [IEs navigate method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752094(v=vs.85).aspx).  Be careful when automating button presses.  If you don't own the website it can change at any time.  This may well break your code, as it is [tightly coupled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)) to the current design.  If the website exposes an [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) you should use that instead.

Comment: Thanks for the input I managed to complete it.